# How to style the element in the list above and below and its subsequent differently using react scss

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, web-frontend

The output should be like this
[image]
I was able to achieve the color differently just below the selected element and other subsequent element differently but I was not able to do it for the above elements of the selected element
my react component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './App.scss'

function App() {
 
   const [list] = useState([{
      time:'10:00',
      selected:false,
   },{
      time:'10:30',
      selected:false,
   },{
      time:'11:00',
      selected:false,
   },{
      time:'11:30',
      selected:true,
   },{
      time:'12:00',
      selected:false,
   },{
      time:'12:30',
      selected:false,
   },{
      time:'01:00',
      selected:false,
   }]);

  return (
   <div className='container'>
<ul className='list'>
   {list.map((item) => (
     <li
       key={item.id}
       className={`item ${item.selected === true ? "selected" : ""}`}
     >
       {item.time}
     </li>
   ))}
 </ul>
   </div>
   
  );
}


export default App
```

and here is scss code

```
.list{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.item{
    display: flex;
    margin: 5px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 28px;
    letter-spacing: 0.35px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    &.selected{
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 22px;
        line-height: 28px;
        letter-spacing: 0.35px;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        &.selected + .item:nth-child(n + 1) {
            font-weight: 400;
            font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 28px;
    letter-spacing: 0.35px;
    background-color: yellow;
          }
          &.selected ~ .item {
            font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 28px;
    letter-spacing: 0.35px;
    background-color: red;
          }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me achieving this please.
I  got stuck getting like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your css file, it will show selected class element in blue back-ground

```css
li.selected {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

className={`item ${item.selected === true ? "selected" : ""}`} you can change background by changing selected element.